# Retrieve information from Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Here's my database on Firebase:

[image: Here's my database on Firebase]

I want to get the user's name after someone has just logged into my app.

```
final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("hellodoctor-65e79/message/user-doctor");

FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    ref = ref.child(user.getUid());

    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            userDoctor[0] = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserDoctor.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

But it doesn't work, please help me, thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: show error please
and what is userDoctor[0]

Comment: From the screenshot it looks like `hellodoctor-65e79` is the name of your database, in which case you shouldn't include it in your call to `ref`. So:  `DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("message/user-doctor");`

Comment: Also: don't ignore `onCancelled` as it may contain crucial information on why your app doesn't work. Instead: `public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in ios with Xcode, not android, but hopefully you can sorta see what is going on.

This is if you just want to retrieve the username. If you want to retrieve all the users details, I would suggest using a NSObject.

```
func retrieveUsername() {
    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else {
        return
    }
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(uid).child("name")

    ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
     print("Username:", snapshot.value as! String)
    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```